# Receive serial data from processing to arduino duemilanove

Tags: arduino, processing

Does anyone has information to receive data commnunication from processing to "arduino duemilanove" by sending "0" or "1" byte through serial ? I've received nothing when communicate from serial to arduino and need someone to further guide me.Those reference I took from websites "https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing"

**My coding in processing:**

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myport;

void setup(){

  String portname = Serial.list()[0]; 
  myport = new Serial(this,portname,9600);

}

void draw(){

  if (myport.available() > 0 )
  {
         myport.write("1");
         println("Print 1 to arduino Now");
  }

}
```

**My coding in arduino : (I'd tried to monitor incoming byte from process in serial monitor)**

```c
int incomingByte = 0 ;

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600); 

}

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() > 0 )
  {
   incomingByte = Serial.read();
   Serial.print("check :");
   Serial.println(incomingByte,DEC);
  }

}
```

The situation is weird where It show nothing happened and returned empty in output once I opened serial monitor to check out. I've managed to pluged in to power arduino(First) and click to run processing(second).
How i could possible to receive "1" from processing to arduino through serial monitor?

Hopw someone could guide me in further, Thanks.

Comment: You has got an interlocking. Both serials are waiting to recieve. `Serial.available() > 0´ means that you have recieved bytes in your serial buffer. Try to do a `myport.write("1");` in Processing's setup(), this will send something to arduino and arduino will answer.